# Angular5 : Installing Angular packages on Sublime Text 3

Tags: angular, sublimetext3

I have already installed NODEJS and Angular on my computer through CLI. Now, in Sublime Text 3. I attempted to install control packages through

1. CTRL + SHIFT + P
2. I typed "install packages" then hit enter.
3. I also typed in ANGULAR CLI then hit enter.

I don't have idea if the installation is on going. It takes several minutes. I don't see any progress on my installation. What I did was i uninstall my Sublime Text 3 for me to reinstall the packages coz i know that I messed it up. After reinstalling sublime text 3, I found out that my project folder is already open in sublime. Now i redo steps 1-3 but what I found out in the console was a message. See screenshots below
[image]
[image]

Now, I really want to know the exact step on installing Angular5 on my SublimeText 3. If possible, I want to have a clean install on the packages. How am I going to do that.? Should I uninstall sublime text 3? How to remove the Angular packages on Sublime Text 3 ?

Thanks a lot for your future feedbacks.

Comment: Can't help you with the Angular package as I don't use it, but I CAN tell you that if you see it saying it's loading something from a package, it's installed.

Comment: Also, re-installing Sublime doesn't affect packages you have installed; use Package Control to remove the package if you want to get rid of it.

Comment: But when I go to Preferences >> Package Settings >> It shows AngularJS option. Does this mean it's successfully installed ?

Comment: If you see something there, yes; not all packages do that though, so not seeing anything there isn't necessarily a problem.

Comment: do you have any idea why my app.module.ts codes are all displayed in white? It doesn't have unlike my .html files

Comment: What syntax does it say it's using in the bottom right of the window? Sublime doesn't support `TypeScript` out of the box (if that's the file that is); you may need to install the `TypeScript` package as well, if the packages you're using don't provide their own syntax for it.

Comment: Try Ctrl+Shift+P and type in the command for package that you installed. For ex- I installed angular cli, to check that I typed in AngularCLI:'command_name'.

Answer (score -1):

Press Ctrl+Shift+P (or Shift+⌘+P on a Mac) type 'Remove' All the packages that can be removed will be shown in the list below. Select one and this is it.

For fresh Installation try out this link. I too was facing issue but following the below link worked for me.

http://blog.netgloo.com/2017/03/09/setup-sublime-text-3-for-angular/